# Magento 2.3 -> 2.4: CLI commands all throw "Area code is not set"

Tags: cli, state, magento-framework

The story so far:
I'm updating Magento from 2.3 to 2.4 and in doing so I'm now getting an "Area code is not set" when running any CLI command. This did not happen in 2.3 and after looking at the following stack trace from bin/magento s:di:c --verbose I have the following stack trace:

```
In State.php line 153:
                                                    
  [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]  
  Area code is not set                              
                                                    

Exception trace:
  at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:153
 Magento\Framework\App\State->getAreaCode() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/State/Interceptor.php:50
 Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->getAreaCode() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme.php:272
 Magento\Theme\Model\Theme->getArea() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/View/File/Collector/Base.php:68
 Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\Base->getFiles() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/View/File/Collector/Decorator/ModuleOutput.php:59
 Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\Decorator\ModuleOutput->getFiles() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/View/File/Collector/Decorator/ModuleDependency.php:63
 Magento\Framework\View\File\Collector\Decorator\ModuleDependency->getFiles() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/File/Collector/Aggregated.php:88
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\File\Collector\Aggregated->getFiles() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/FileCollector/AggregatedFileCollector.php:76
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\FileCollector\AggregatedFileCollector->collectFiles() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Reader/FileResolver.php:43
 Magento\Ui\Config\Reader\FileResolver->get() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Reader/Definition.php:28
 Magento\Ui\Config\Reader\Definition->read() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Reader/Definition/Data.php:89
 Magento\Ui\Config\Reader\Definition\Data->initData() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Reader/Definition/Data.php:75
 Magento\Ui\Config\Reader\Definition\Data->__construct() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:206
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:182
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/View/LayoutFactory.php:50
 Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php:79
 Magento\Payment\Helper\Data->__construct() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/generated/code/Magento/Payment/Helper/Data/Interceptor.php:14
 Magento\Payment\Helper\Data\Interceptor->__construct() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:206
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:182
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:153
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:134
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1274
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:629
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:237
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:115
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/bin/magento:23
```

The stand out line is:

```
 Magento\Theme\Model\Theme->getArea() at /var/www/OUR_COMPANY/vendor/magento/framework/View/File/Collector/Base.php:68
```

When we open up vendor/magento/framework/View/File/Collector/Base.php in 2.3 & 2.4 we see the following:

In 2.4

```
/**
     * Retrieve files
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Design\ThemeInterface $theme
     * @param string $filePath
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\File[]
     */
    public function getFiles(ThemeInterface $theme, $filePath)
    {
        $result = [];
        $sharedFiles = $this->componentDirSearch->collectFilesWithContext(
            ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
            "view/base/{$this->subDir}{$filePath}"
        );
        foreach ($sharedFiles as $file) {
            $result[] = $this->fileFactory->create($file->getFullPath(), $file->getComponentName(), null, true);
        }
        $area = $theme->getArea(); <-- This line is important
        $themeFiles = $this->componentDirSearch->collectFilesWithContext(
            ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
            "view/{$area}/{$this->subDir}{$filePath}"
        );
        foreach ($themeFiles as $file) {
            $result[] = $this->fileFactory->create($file->getFullPath(), $file->getComponentName());
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

In 2.3:

```
/**
     * Retrieve files
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Design\ThemeInterface $theme
     * @param string $filePath
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\File[]
     */
    public function getFiles(ThemeInterface $theme, $filePath)
    {
        $result = [];
        $sharedFiles = $this->componentDirSearch->collectFilesWithContext(
            ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
            "view/base/{$this->subDir}{$filePath}"
        );
        foreach ($sharedFiles as $file) {
            $result[] = $this->fileFactory->create($file->getFullPath(), $file->getComponentName(), null, true);
        }
        $area = $theme->getData('area'); <-- This line is important
        $themeFiles = $this->componentDirSearch->collectFilesWithContext(
            ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
            "view/{$area}/{$this->subDir}{$filePath}"
        );
        foreach ($themeFiles as $file) {
            $result[] = $this->fileFactory->create($file->getFullPath(), $file->getComponentName());
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

The large difference are the corresponding lines:

```
2.3: $area = $theme->getData('area');

vs

2.4: $area = $theme->getArea();
```

getArea() will throw a \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException if the area code is not set, while getData('area') will return null if the area code is not set.

Now I imagine a correct solution is setting the area code appropriately elsewhere. But I haven't the slightest idea as to where.

My next hunch is to override the class and implement the default behavior of returning null which is what all our 2.3 code would expect. However this is almost certainly not the right path. In addition when I do override vendor/magento/framework/View/File/Collector/Base.php the CLI ignores the override.

**Update October / 7 / 2021**

So a solution is to skip the update to 2.4.3 and only update to 2.4.2
You can find the PR that caused the issue [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/28917#issuecomment-934949326). In additon the best solution I can recomend is the one mentioned [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/28917#issuecomment-934949326) where you wrap that section in a try / catch block. Editing vendor files is not a long term solution but it will get you back on your feet untill a patch is made.